# Shinyapps.io problem when importing hdf5 model

Tags: r, shiny

Want to build app importing a CNN model from the hdf5 file with the keras package

model<-load_model_hdf5("tufts3.hdf5")

(The file is uploaded during the install phase)

After this, I ran into error messages , I have tried creating a virtual Python environment with:

reticulate::virtualenv_install('r-tensorflow', c('h5py',tensorflow','keras')),

but I get the container out of memory in the shinyapps.io log.

Anyone knows how these machine learning models can be read?

Comment: "but I get the container out of memory in the shinyapps.io log." you seem to have answered your own question - you need more RAM